# How do I read the results of a stored proc into it's complex type

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I've created my stored procedure, I've created the complex type using the entity model. Now assuming I have successfully established a connection to the database - I'm now ready to run the store procedure and store the rows in a `List<ComplexType>`. How do I do this in the best, most efficient way? I'm aware that I can iterate through the columns and rows of an SQLDataReader but it sort of feels like I'd be missing the point of the entity framework.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the stored procedure as a function import and then call it in your assembly directly:

```
Using (var context = new NorthwindEntities())
{
               Var query = context.GetEmployeeNames(); // we import the stored procedure as a function GetEmployeeNames().
               //…
}
```

If you use OUTPUT parameter in your stored procedure, you need to add ObjectParameters to get the return value. For example,

```
Using(var context = new NorthwindEntities())
{
               ObjectParameter firstname = new ObjectParameter(“firstname”, typeof(String));
               ObjectParameter lastname  = new ObjectParameter(“lastname”, typeof(String));
               Var query = context.GetEmployeeByID(123, firstname, lastname);
               // Console.WriteLine(“Employee {0}’s name is: {1}.{2}.”, 123, firstname, lastname);
}
```

Here is a live sample:

[image]

**ReferralVisitors** is a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitry, really appreciate your response. I seem to be getting the following error though: "The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'NorthwindModel.StoredProcedure_Result'. A member of the type, 'Column1', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name."

Comment: In the above case, Column1 refers to a Count column. Any help is seriously appreciated!

Comment: @SkonJeet   "NorthwindEntities" is only some example. Perhaps you have to use your own data context name.

Comment: I know sorry, ignore that for now - I put that in myself too (to fill the space). The problem is that the complex type doesn't match the result for some reason!? But I've only just created it so I don't know where the mismatch is.

Comment: @SkonJeet I just put the live sample in C#.

Comment: Dmitry, thanks so much! I solved it by giving each column an alias in the stored procedure. Thanks again for your help, your original suggestion is what's cracked my problem for me.